# Searching JDBC for entry

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a successfully connected Database Manager (simple Phonebook) with some functional options like add and get all entries. Now I need to prepare a Select option, that will allow the user to search for a first, last or full name in the Table.

The menu option is working, but I´m having some problem searching the Database for that specific name. What´s the correct syntax?

I´m trying something like this without success:

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName LIKE '%"     + nameThatIsBeingSearched + "%');
```

I´m getting a com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'TABLE_NAME' in 'where clause'.

Is it possible to just get the column name automatically? There´s only one column, and I´m having difficulties trying to find it´s name.

Comment: Well, what is the name of your table? If there is only one column you can always use * in the select clause.

Comment: TableName is PhoneBook. Tried: resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PhoneBook WHERE * LIKE '%" + name + "%'"); and got com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException saying to check for the right syntax to use near '* LIKE '%John%''

Comment: Ah sorry, the * only works for the select clause, not the where part. You still need to know the column name there.

Comment: Find out the name! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following syntax for adding enlargements to your sql query

```
 String insertSQL = "SELECT * FROM DatabaseName WHERE ColumnName LIKE %?"
            PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement(insertSQL);
            stat.setString(1,nameThatIsBeingSearche);          
            ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement looks okay. What is your problem? No results or wrong results?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM DatabaseName WHERE ColumnName LIKE '%"     + nameThatIsBeingSearched + "%');
```

By

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName LIKE '%"     + nameThatIsBeingSearched + "%');
```

Answer (score 0):

The query looks correct, only instead DatabaseName should be the name of the table.